# Extract values from python list using bash

Tags: bash

This is my bash program:

```
YOLO_ARRAY=( '[0.1, 0.5, 0.6]' )

for YOLO in "${YOLO_ARRAY[@}}"
do
    :
    # store string of elements in yolo
    # i.e.
    # YOLO="0.10.50.6"
done
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve the sudo code here?

Answer (score 0):

The comments can be replaced  with:

```
YOLO=$(echo $YOLO | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g')
```

This will match all items in the string $YOLO that are not a number or dot, and remove them, leaving you with what I wanted.